# What is the minimum permission level needed to manage the retention schedule of a folder?

Tags: permissions, records-management, information-policy

Say I have a record library that has already been set up to have a retention source of "Library and Folders".

Someone adds a folder.  They use the context menu to view compliance details.  In the compliance details, they click on "Manage the retention schedule for items in this folder."

What is the minimum permission they need in order to be able to get to the retention stages, and not get an access denied error?

[I'm looking for the granular permission here, like "Edit Items" or "View Pages", not the higher level "Contribute" or "Design" etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, it seems that the permission needed is "Manage Lists."